# Making a callback in a mousemove handler asynchronous

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following event handler. Due to their frequency with which it occurs, it will be pretty "greedy". `onMouseMove`, it will draw a "lasso" around the selected area, then perform a throttled geospatial search around the area.

```
onMouseMove = ({ pageX, pageY }: MouseEvent) => {
  const lasso = this.getLasso(pageX, pageY);
  this.ctx.setLineDash([6]);
  this.ctx.strokeStyle = '#ffffff';
  this.ctx.strokeRect(lasso.left, lasso.top, lasso.width, lasso.height);

  // this is the problem area.
  this.props.onSelection(this.search(lasso));
}
```

However, I find the callstack is largely just about running this callback. The action to update the "lasso" is only 2ms, but the `onSelection` callback takes ~40ms. They're both grouped under `Event (mousemove)` in performance. I think this is making the animation of the lasso look very choppy.

[image]

Would there be a way to run this callback independently/asynchronously from the mouse event handler? It doesn't so much matter to the mousemove event when it completes.

Comment: You should use a Web Worker - it will start a separate thread so as to not block the main thread. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) with a delay of 0. It will be added to the JavaScript scheduler queue, and run after the current callstack finishes.

In situ, this becomes:

```
onMouseMove = ({ pageX, pageY }: MouseEvent) => {
  const lasso = this.getLasso(pageX, pageY);
  this.ctx.setLineDash([6]);
  this.ctx.strokeStyle = '#ffffff';
  this.ctx.strokeRect(lasso.left, lasso.top, lasso.width, lasso.height);

  // this is the problem area.
  setTimeout(function () { this.props.onSelection(this.search(lasso));});
}
```

Since 0 is the default, you may omit it, as shown in the linked docs:

> If this parameter is omitted, a value of 0 is used, meaning execute "immediately", or more accurately, as soon as possible. Note that in either case, the actual delay may be longer than intended; see [Reasons for delays longer than specified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified) below.

Comment: or you can use `requestAnimationFrame` if you really want

Comment: @Ven I assume the OP would want to call that before the problem area, so the re-render happened before the slow callback finished? I've never used that before.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, my intention was not to waste work. I see now that your first comment was meant to provoke me to thought. I'm beginning to see what you mean. It was worthless without the link.

Comment: `window.requestAnimationFrame` did work quite well! Thank you sir

Comment: @corvid Could you post that as an answer? I'd be curious to see how it works. I've never used `requestAnimationFrame`

Comment: I just did a curried function and called it with `window.requestAnimationFrame`. Basically just `window.requestAnimationFrame(this.select(lasso))`. Worked perfectly.

Comment: In that case, perhaps you (or @Ven) should post it as an answer, and then accept it.